# Valgrind reports memory leak on QThread::start()

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, qt5, valgrind, qthread

The issue is on VMware, somehow 3D acceleration causes memory leak and SIGSEGV, resulting in program crashing.

=============================

I have a problem with following codes:

```
    gc = new GameController(scene);
    subthread = new QThread(this);
    gc->moveToThread(subthread);
    subthread->start();
```

This should be a regular sub-thread initialization, but valgrind memory analyzer says:

```
416 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 8,318 of 8,856
  in Widget::Widget(QWidget*) in /home/closer_ex/QtProjects/LifeGameWithTest/LifeGame/widget.cpp:15
  1: calloc in /builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.15.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:762
  2: allocate_dtv in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
  3: _dl_allocate_tls in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
  4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so
  5: QThread::start(QThread::Priority) in /home/closer_ex/Qt5.13.2/5.13.2/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.13.2
  6: Widget::Widget(QWidget*) in /home/closer_ex/QtProjects/LifeGameWithTest/LifeGame/widget.cpp:15
  7: main in /home/closer_ex/QtProjects/LifeGameWithTest/LifeGame/main.cpp:8
```

directly pointing to `subthread->start()`.
The `scene` is not the parent but a QGraphicsScene pointer passed to do some computing in sub-thread, and I manually `delete gc` after quit()&wait() `subthread` in my destructor. The program runs smoothly, but I cant do any memory analyzing because of this.

There are 2 definite leaks if I check External Errors, leading to `QApplication a(argc, argv);` and `malloc` in 'vg_replace_malloc.c'.

```
544 bytes in 11 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8,418 of 8,861
  in _dl_close_worker in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
  1: malloc in /builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.15.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:309
  2: _dl_close_worker in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
  3: _dl_close in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
  4: _dl_catch_exception in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
  5: _dl_catch_error in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
  6: _dlerror_run in /usr/lib64/libdl-2.28.so
  7: dlclose in /usr/lib64/libdl-2.28.so
  8: g_module_close in /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  9: /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  10: g_type_module_unuse in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  11: /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  12: g_io_extension_point_get_extensions in /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  13: /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  14: g_settings_backend_get_default in /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  15: /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  16: /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  17: g_object_new_valist in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  18: g_object_new in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  19: g_settings_new_full in /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4
  20: /usr/lib64/libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30
  21: /usr/lib64/libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30
  22: gdk_display_manager_open_display in /usr/lib64/libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30
  23: gtk_init_check in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.2200.30
  24: gtk_init in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.2200.30
  25: QGtk3Theme::QGtk3Theme() in /home/closer_ex/Qt5.13.2/5.13.2/gcc_64/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk3.so
```

Where could the leak happen?

Comment: I don't know, but my guess is that the `GameController` object doesn't take ownership of the thread object you provide to `moveToThread`, so you still have to `delete subthread;`.

Comment: what is the line of code in widget.cpp:15 ?

Comment: @OznOg it is ```subthread->start();``` as my title says

Comment: is the thread joined before exiting?

Comment: @FredLarson ```subthread``` already get a parent, ```this``` points to the mainwindow object.

Comment: @OznOg I think ```wait()``` does the job, unless it timed out -- which is more unlikely to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the GTK+ style in your Qt application. That's clearly visible in the call stack from the crash: all those symbols that contain `gtk` in them are the GTK+ Qt style. This is bad news in most cases as far as profiling or memory leak testing is concerned.

Start your program like `myprogram -style Fusion` - that way the `GTK+` style won't be used.

For example, to start it under valgrind:

```
valgrind myprogram -style Fusion
```

You don't want to be fixing GTK and Qt/GTK interop layer bugs along with your own code :)

Comment: thanks but what exactly should I do? really new to linux here :(

Comment: Have you started your program like `program -style Fusion`? Of course substitute `program` with whatever name your program really has.

Comment: running with fusion style still gives the same leak error, I'll try looking into it later since it's midnight here now

Comment: But you shouldn't be crashing anymore. At least the backtrace should be vastly different. And there should be no "leak" in `QGtk` style plugin code, since you won't be using that plugin anymore. The "leak" you're getting is not an actual leak anyway.

Comment: no it shouldn't, but I found that the issue is not about gtk. Just ran callgrind and program crashed, reporting memory issue in ```vmwgfx_dri.so``` and ```libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0```. Then I realize it is a VMware issue, most likely relevant to 3d acceleration, and unchecking "Accelerate 3D Graphics" fixes everything :) Thanks for your hints though, i might die checking my code if not shown another aspect of the problem

Answer (score 1):

> 416 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 8,318 of 8,856

The message is ***possibly** lost*, that means the Widget is still reachable, this is not a definitive memory leak like in `int * x=new int; x = NULL;`

You have that message because when your program finishes you did not deleted/freed all the allocated dynamic memory, that does not means your program is wrong.

Look at *definitely lost* blocks, if you do not have all is ok in fact. For that you can use the option `--show-leak-kinds=definite` which is equivalent to do `--show-reachable=no --show-possibly-lost=no`

Comment: that's a relief to hear, but the problem is valgrind crashed with the program right here and I cant do further memory analyzing. this is the only message btw.

Comment: @closer_ex It crashed ? I never see it doing a crash when producing the final report including *memory leaks*. Can you redo with the option `--show-leak-kinds=definite` ?

Comment: found 2 definite leak in External Errors, one leading to ```QApplication a(argc, argv);``` in main, the other in malloc from 'vg_replace_malloc.c'. Also with a whole lot more possible leaks in external errors pointing nowhere

Comment: `vg_replace_malloc.c` is internal, look at from where `malloc` is called (just under in the call stack)

Comment: sry for late responding, vm stucked for a while. I cant open this file, even with root permission, but it indicates line 309:0

Comment: @closer_ex I do not ask you to look at `vg_replace_malloc.c` but to look at the stack produced by *valgrind* in the report

Comment: @closer_ex your stack is very strange, you have an exception so may be a crash at the execution (independently of *valgrind*) ?

Comment: running callgrind gave me some issues on ```vmwgfx_dri.so```, so I assume it's a VMware issue and i'm right. unchecking "Accelerate 3D Graphics" fixed it and everything is good now. thanks for your advise :)